# Specify which version of python duplicity should use

Tags: bash, scripting, python, duplicity

I've got a backup script that utilizes duplicity to upload to Dropbox. It's erroring out because the dropbox-python-sdk version required, 6.9.0, uses the keyword `async` which is now reserved in python3. I have both python3 and python2.7 installed on my system, but duplicity is automatically using python3. How can I configure my system, this script, or duplicity, to specifically run python2.7 (in this case, `/usr/bin/pthyon`)?

Comment: Are you using an old version? All those projects currently support python 3.x

Comment: I'm using duplicity 0.8.12, which told me that I need dropbox-python-sdk 6.9.0 when I tried to run a Dropbox command.

Comment: probably dropbox-sdk v6.9+ is needed? how about trying latest version dropbox-sdk v10.x (https://pypi.org/project/dropbox/#history)?

and of course you can still prepend duplicity with a specific python interpreter eg. `python2.7 duplicity ...`

Comment: @ede aha! That could do the trick, will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know duplicity but if it's only 1 script or a combination of a tiny number of scripts then changing `#!/usr/bn/python` to `#!/usr/bin/python3` on the 1st line of the script should do the trick.

Otherwise you can change the symlink `/usr/bin/python` points to. On most distro's there is a 'clean' way to do this but the following will work everywhere:
`sudo ln -sf $(which python3) /usr/bin/python`